# Including header doesn't work

Tags: c++, include, header-files

I am trying a library which is using multiple declarations in `time.h` and `sys/time.h` headers.
Whatever I do I couldn't use the headers in the any of the cpp files. The definition seems like they haven't defined at all.

This is what time.h looks like -

```
#ifndef IW_STD_TIME_H
#define IW_STD_TIME_H

#include <sys/types.h>

#ifndef _TIME_T_DEFINED
#define _TIME_T_DEFINED
typedef long time_t;
#endif

#define CLOCKS_PER_SEC 1000

#ifndef _CLOCK_T_DEFINED
typedef long clock_t;
#define _CLOCK_T_DEFINED
#endif

#ifndef _TM_DEFINED
struct tm
{
    int tm_sec;     /* seconds after the minute - [0,59] */
    int tm_min;     /* minutes after the hour - [0,59] */
    int tm_hour;    /* hours since midnight - [0,23] */
    int tm_mday;    /* day of the month - [1,31] */
    int tm_mon;     /* months since January - [0,11] */
    int tm_year;    /* years since 1900 */
    int tm_wday;    /* days since Sunday - [0,6] */
    int tm_yday;    /* days since January 1 - [0,365] */
    int tm_isdst;   /* daylight savings time flag */
};
#define _TM_DEFINED
#endif

struct timespec
{
    time_t tv_sec;          /* Seconds.  */
    long int tv_nsec;       /* Nanoseconds.  */
};

S3E_BEGIN_C_DECL

#ifdef __ARMCC_VERSION
#define localtime localtime_rvct
#define localtime_r localtime_rvct_r
#endif

time_t time(time_t *t);

void tzset(void);

char *asctime(const struct tm *tm);
char *asctime_r(const struct tm *tm, char *buf);

char *ctime(const time_t *timep);
char *ctime_r(const time_t *timep, char *buf);

struct tm *gmtime(const time_t *timep);
struct tm *gmtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);

struct tm *localtime(const time_t *timep);
struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);

time_t mktime(struct tm *tm);

size_t strftime(char *s, size_t max, const char *format, const struct tm *tm);

clock_t clock(void);

double difftime(time_t time1, time_t time0);

int nanosleep(const struct timespec *req, struct timespec *rem);


#if defined __GNUC__ && !defined __APPLE__ && !defined I3D_ARCH_MIPS
    extern char *_tzname[2];
    extern int _daylight;
    extern long int _timezone;
    #define tzname _tzname
    #define daylight _daylight
    #define timezone _timezone
#else
    extern char *tzname[2];
    extern int daylight;
    extern long int timezone;
#endif

#define CLOCK_REALTIME 1
#define CLOCK_MONOTONIC 2

typedef int clockid_t;

int clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);

int clock_gettime(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *tp);

int clock_settime(clockid_t clk_id, const struct timespec *tp);

S3E_END_C_DECL

#include <sys/time.h>

#endif /* !IW_STD_TIME_H */
```

and this is how sys/time.h is defined -

```
#ifndef IW_STD_SYS_TIME_H
#define IW_STD_SYS_TIME_H

#include "s3eTypes.h"
#include <time.h>

#ifndef _WINSOCK2API_

S3E_BEGIN_C_DECL

#ifndef _TIME_T_DEFINED
#define _TIME_T_DEFINED
typedef long time_t;
#endif

typedef long suseconds_t;
struct timeval
{
    time_t      tv_sec;     /* seconds */
    suseconds_t tv_usec;    /* microseconds */
};

struct timezone
{
    int tz_minuteswest;     /* minutes west of Greenwich */
    int tz_dsttime;         /* type of DST correction */
};

int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);
int settimeofday(const struct timeval *tv , const struct timezone *tz);

int utimes(const char *filename, const struct timeval times[2]);

S3E_END_C_DECL

#endif  // XBOX

#endif // !IW_STD_SYS_TIME_H
```

I include them in the cpp files as `#include<time.h>` and not even the `typedef long time_t;` works. However when I put the declaration in the cpp file itself, it works. I am sure I am missing something silly here. Any idea?

PS: This is how the macros mentioned in the file are defined -

```
#define S3E_BEGIN_C_DECL extern "C" {
#define S3E_END_C_DECL }
```

Update:

The errors are like this -

Error   3   error C2079: 'tv' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
Error   4   error C3861: 'gettimeofday': identifier not found

It seems as if the all the definition in the header is not defined at all. And this is happening everywhere with these headers.

Comment: What _doesn't work exactly_? Be explicit please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the definition doesn't work. I am getting errors like undefined or syntax errors. Here's the example of some of the errors - 
    `Error 3 error C2079: 'tv' uses undefined struct 'timeval'
    Error 4 error C3861: 'gettimeofday': identifier not found`

I mean I can't use the definition, even if I include the header.

Comment: Have you `#include`d `<sys/time.h>` or just `<time.h>`? If you haven't included both, do so.

Comment: @Wintermute I've tried to include both, but as you can see `time.h` includes `sys/time.h` already, so I suppose this shouldn't be required. Although including both also doesn't change anything.

Comment: Oh, at the end. I only saw the `<sys/types.h>` at the beginning. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohk it was because there's a `time.h` already there in my project and a `#include_next` directive was used to replace default header. I commented out that directive earlier, so I suppose that's why the IDE was showing the right file, but compiler was taking the replaced file into account. I changed the `#include_next` with a `#include` putting a more specific path of the default file and the error was solved.